# Counting hundred thousands of data causesCross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I execute my request code with little count value, it is working but when a count value is returning more than 30,000 it starts to cause an error. please help, here is the screenshot of my code and error.

The 30,000 is just based on observation but the point is if it is returning a high count value it throws an error. I need to count the number of documents even if it is greater than 30,000.

Or please help me another solution on how to count massive amounts of data on mongodb using nodejs. Thanks.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvN9Z.png)

[Success Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npd5o.png)

Here is the code below

```
router.post("/count/:collection", authenticate, (request, response) => {
var collection;
switch (request.params.collection) {
case "region":
  collection = Region;
  queryCollection = Region;
  break;

case "citymun":
  collection = Citymun;
  queryCollection = Citymun;
  break;

case "encoder":
  collection = Encoder;
  queryCollection = Encoder;
  break;

case "verifier":
  collection = Verifier;
  queryCollection = Verifier;
  break;

case "superadmin":
  collection = Superadmin;
  queryCollection = Superadmin;
  break;

case "population":
  collection = Population;
  queryCollection = Population;
  break;

case "interview":
  collection = Interview;
  queryCollection = Interview;
  break;

case "barangay":
  collection = Barangay;
  queryCollection = Barangay;
  break;

case "province":
  collection = Province;
  queryCollection = Province;
  break;

case "user":
  collection = User;
  queryCollection = User;
  break;

case "subscription":
  collection = Subscription;
  queryCollection = Subscription;
  break;

default:
  break;
 }

 if (!collection)
return response.send({ type: 501, message: "Request not acceptable" });



var flag = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {
if (request.body[i].$limit) flag = i;
}

if (flag != -1) {
request.body.splice(flag, 1);
}

flag = -1;
for (var j = 0; j < request.body.length; j++) {
if (request.body[j].$skip || request.body[j].$skip == 0) flag = j;
}

if (flag != -1) {
request.body.splice(flag, 1);
}
request.body.splice(flag, 1);

request.body.push({
$count: "count"
});

console.log(request.body);

var cursor = collection
.aggregate(request.body)
.cursor({ batchSize: 100 })
.exec(function() {
  // never cause
});

cursor
.on("error", function(err) {
  response.send({ type: 500, data: err });
})
.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  response.send({ type: 200, data: data });
})
.on("end", function() {
  console.log("end");
});


});
```

Comment: check if exceeding limits: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits

Comment: Can't think of the possible cause of your error. Have you tried `db.collection.mapReduce()` to count big numbers? It's always a good idea to let the db do the work and minimize traffic with application server.

Comment: thanks @RaphaMex, I will try that.